# y values of a list into the x values of another list

Tags: list-manipulation, data, dataset

If I have two lists such as:

```
list1 = {{15, 3.2891166646450087`}, {15,3.360635129695413`}, {15, 3.3457315005021853`}, {15,3.342117982645869`}, {15, 3.3322981661048416`}, {15, 3.265515442417647`}};

list2 = {{15, 10.520000000000003`}, {15,11.380000000000003`}, {15, 12.149999999999999`}, {15,12.810000000000002`}, {15, 12.950000000000003`}, {15, 13.04`}};
```

**Question:**

How can I put put y values of list 2 into the x values of list 1? For example as to create a new list such as:

```
listnew={{10.520000000000003`, 3.2891166646450087`}, {11.380000000000003`,3.360635129695413`}, {12.149999999999999`, 3.3457315005021853`}, {12.810000000000002`,3.342117982645869`}, {12.950000000000003`, 3.3322981661048416`}, {13.04`, 3.265515442417647`}};
```

Comment: ```MapThread[{#2[[2]], #1[[2]]} &, {list1, list2}]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Transpose[{list2[[All, -1]], list1[[All, -1]]}]
```